# std::map try emplace vs emplace strange behaviour

Tags: c++, stdmap, emplace

The common advice is to prefer using `std::map::try_emplace` in preference to `std::map::emplace` in almost every instance.

I wrote a simple test to trace object creation/copying/moving/destruction when calling those functions, with and without clashes, and the results show that `try_emplace` incurs an extra move and destruction of the key when it is not already in the map.

Why the difference in behaviour?

I do know that moves and destructions of moved-from objects are usually cheap, especially so for trivial keys, but I was still surprised by the results as they seem to imply that for some cases `emplace` might be more efficient.

[Compiler explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/joM7x6bss) (Clang 14, libc++, -O3)

Source:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

struct F {
    F(int i): i(i) { std::cout << "- ctor (" << i << ")\n"; }
    ~F() { std::cout << "- dtor (" << i << ")\n"; }
    F(const F& f): i(f.i) { std::cout << "- copy ctor (" << i << ")\n"; }
    F(F&& f): i(f.i) { std::cout << "- move ctor (" << i << ")\n"; }
    F& operator=(const F& f) { i = f.i; std::cout << "- copy (" << i << ")\n"; return *this; }
    F& operator=(F&& f) { i = f.i; std::cout << "- move (" << i << ")\n"; return *this; }
    bool operator <(const F& f) const { return i < f.i; }
    int i{};
};

int main() {
    std::map<F, F> m;
    std::cout << "emplace 1:\n";
    m.emplace(1, 2);
    std::cout << "emplace 2:\n";
    m.emplace(1, 3);
    std::cout << "clear:\n";
    m.clear();
    std::cout << "try_emplace 1:\n";
    m.try_emplace(1, 2);
    std::cout << "try_emplace 2:\n";
    m.try_emplace(1, 3);
    std::cout << "done:\n";
}
```

Results:

```
emplace 1:
- ctor (1)
- ctor (2)
emplace 2:
- ctor (1)
- ctor (3)
- dtor (3)
- dtor (1)
clear:
- dtor (2)
- dtor (1)
try_emplace 1:
- ctor (1)
- move ctor (1)
- ctor (2)
- dtor (1)
try_emplace 2:
- ctor (1)
- dtor (1)
done:
- dtor (2)
- dtor (1)
```

Comment: How do you expect it to *check* if the key exists without constructing it first? `try_emplace` is making the key, checking if it's already in the map, if not, moving it into its final storage location and constructing the value directly in place.

Comment: `emplace` is more efficient if we *know* that the key is not present, because then we can skip the "try" and just create the node.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, `emplace` also does, but with fewer ctors/moves.

Comment: @AlexO: `emplace` can construct the complete `std::pair` at once as part of a node to be inserted, and insert that raw node into the `map` if it does not exist, and discard it if it already exists. `try_emplace` guarantees it won't construct the value unless it needs to, so it can't construct the complete `std::pair` until it *knows* the key is not present, so it has to make the key first, check for it, then make the `pair` only if it's not found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between the two functions is:

- `std::map::emplace` constructs a `value_type`, i.e. a `std::pair` in-place, and then attempts to insert this pair.
- `std::map::try_emplace` attempts to find an insert location first, and if one is found, it will construct the `value_type`, i.e. a `std::pair` in-place.

`try_emplace` appears to save us some work, but remember that even if we don't insert anything new into the map with `try_emplace`, we still have to check whether we can, and where. This happens with `std::less` by default, which ends up calling:

```cpp
bool operator<(const F& f) const { return i < f.i; }
```

**An `F` object must exist** to perform this comparison, and is being constructed once during `try_emplace`.

Let's annotate your example with what is happening:

```cpp
emplace 1:
 - ctor (1) // construct node{1, 2}
 - ctor (2)
emplace 2:
 - ctor (1) // construct node{1, 3}
 - ctor (3)
 - dtor (3) // can't insert, destroy node{1, 3}
 - dtor (1)

clear:
 - dtor (2) // destroy node{1, 2}
 - dtor (1)

try_emplace 1:
 - ctor (1) // construct temporary key
 - move_ctor (1) // location found, move key to node
 - ctor (2) // construct value
 - dtor (1) // destroy temporary key
try_emplace 2:
 - ctor (1) // construct temporary key
 - dtor (1) // destroy temporary key
done:
 - dtor (2) // destroy node{1, 2}
 - dtor (1)
```

#### Conclusion

We can't say that `emplace` is universally better or worse than `try_emplace`, rather there is a trade-off:

| No Pre-Existing Key | Insertion Success | Insertion Failure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `emplace` | zero overhead<sup>1)</sup> | wasted key and value initialization |
| `try_emplace` | wasted key move | wasted key initialization |

The trade-off changes when we have a pre-existing key instead of initializing one inside of `try_emplace` or `emplace`:

| Pre-Existing Key | Insertion Success | Insertion Failure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `emplace` | wasted key move | wasted key move & init, wasted value init |
| `try_emplace` | wasted key move | zero overhead |

In conclusion, `try_emplace` is at worst wasting one move constructor compared to `emplace`, and at best, it's strictly better. Prefer it in most, but not all cases.

---

<sup>1)</sup> *"overhead" is relative to magically knowing the right location (or absence thereof) in the map and initializing a node in-place. Initialization of the pre-existing key is considered free.*