# Why does the emplace method in std::unordered_map take multiple parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, unordered-map, emplace

This was a source of confusion for me, but std::unordered_map::try_emplace takes the key and variable arguments for the constructor of the value(mapped) type, however ::emplace is supposed to take an std::pair<key, value>:

> In addition, try_emplace treats the key and the arguments to the
> mapped_type separately, unlike emplace, which requires the arguments
> to construct a value_type (that is, a std::pair).

Ok, that is confusing. Why is it that the function signature is:

```
template< class... Args >
std::pair<iterator, bool> emplace( Args&&... args );
```

Why the multiple arguments if you're required to construct an std::pair<key, value> as described above?

Comment: All `emplace` overloads on all the containers construct a `Container::value_type`, which in the case of maps was already a pair since 98. That's just the overreaching design principle. They did notice it's less than ideal for maps, because `std::pair` got its `std::piecewise_construct` overload. Then `try_emplace` came into being after `emplace` was tested in the wild. It's important to remember that this spec evolves over time, not designed entirely in advance.

Comment: Yes, my understanding is that for associative containers the emplace pattern is simply misleading at best. There are detailed reasons for this. My rule of thumb is that if the program needs to construct to object just to see where and whether to insert it, it probably means that there will no much gain in doing it.

Comment: And when you do design everything in advance it's good to remember that A) no plan survives contact with the enemy and B) the enemy is us.

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is because `emplace` is really designed to forward the parameters to the constructor of the object.
(It can be the copy constructor, in which case you use only one parameter with the value (or r-value0 you want to store, but it doesn't need to be).

In this particular example, it the value is `std::pair` so it is less useful.

Example:

```
#include<unordered_map>

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<int, double> m;
    m.emplace(42, 3.14);  // the constructor of pair will be called with these two parameters.
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/PYx51jT4x

Some people do not recommend using emplace for some containers because there is really not much gain and it can be misleading, because many times the value will be constructed anyway before knowing "where" in needs to be and then copied there, instead of really emplaced.

Take a look at Meyer's book, "Effective Modern C++: 42 Specific Ways to Improve Your Use of C++11 and C++14"

Not sure now if `unordered_set` is one of these.

Comment: What object? std::pair<key, value> or value?

Comment: @Zebrafish, good point, the `pair`, which makes the idiom less useful and probably not even an optimization over insert in this case. See my edit.

Comment: "_because there is really not much gain and it can be misleading_": It is important when the element type is non-movable or if a move is costly. I do not really see much of a difference to the other containers. "_and then copied there, instead of really emplaced._": That's not allowed. `emplace` only requires Cpp17EmplaceConstructible.

Comment: Also, `std::pair` has constructors taking zero, one and three arguments as well. They need to be supported, too. It would be weird to write multiple `emplace` overloads just for that.

Comment: @user17732522, Cpp17EmplaceConstructible, for the value type or for the whole pair? that would make a different if the all the elements of the args except the first are forwarded to the constructor. Is that what it does?

Comment: @alfC Cpp17EmplaceConstructible for the whole pair. So `emplace` itself can only ever construct one key and mapped value, directly into a single pair. It can't make a copy/move. But, in contrast to `try_emplace` which _must_ make a copy/move of the key when it is actually inserted, `emplace` _must_ always construct the whole pair in order to get the key to compare to. `try_emplace` can avoid constructing the mapped value if the key already exists.

Comment: @user17732522, if emplace has to construct it first, then it is not emplacing it really. is it? Yeah, I don't see a use case for emplace in the current form: https://godbolt.org/z/e9v5dP13d .

Comment: @alfC The one construction is the emplacing.

Comment: See my answer for an example showing where _only_ emplace can be used to insert an element.

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, `try_emplace` does what I imagined a useful emplace would do. I guess that the only thing `emplace` could achieve is moving the just constructed object, but so can `insert`. I guess I don't understand what `emplace(kas..., vas ...)` can do that `insert({key{kas...}, value{vas...})` cannot achieve, in terms of semantics and performance. https://godbolt.org/z/bMW55Exv8

Comment: @alfC Both of your examples perform a move operation on both the key and mapped type. With `emplace(std::piecewise_construct, ..., ....);` neither is required. That's the only case I am talking about.

Comment: @user17732522, Now I see your answer, I understand now. (before I was looking to the other answer). Is the fact that the key is non-copyable or expensive to copy fundamental in your example? Because if so, I would claim that that is the real problem here. https://godbolt.org/z/7EePbx3r6

Comment: @alfC Yes, it is only preferable over `try_emplace` if the key is non-movable or costly to move (e.g. containing a large array), but constructing the mapped type is comparably cheap.

Comment: @user17732522, yes, this is what happens when you need to bring your tiny house all the way to the big unmovable key for it to open the door.

Answer (score 1):

For all containers `emplace` takes the arguments and forwards them to the constructor of the `value_type`, which is an `std::pair` of the `const` key and mapped type for a `std::unordered_map`.

`std::pair` has constructors that take 0, 1, 2, and 3 arguments. So `emplace` should support all of them. It is true that there are no `std::pair` constructors that allow more than 3 arguments specified in the standard library, but there wouldn't be much gained specifying *this particular* `emplace` to accept only up to 3 arguments.

Also, a user is allowed to specialize `std::pair` for their own types (as long as it satisfies the standard library requirements) and may add a constructor that takes more than 3 arguments. In that case `emplace` should not unnecessarily be imcompatible.

Here is an example where the only possible way to insert elements into the map is with three arguments to `emplace`, because the key type is non-movable, using the `std::piecewise_construct` constructor of `std::pair` which avoids all copies/moves of the key or mapped type.

```
struct Key {
    int i;
    Key(int i) : i(i) {}
    Key(const Key&) = delete;
    Key& operator=(const Key&) = delete;
    bool operator==(const Key&) const = default;
};

constexpr auto hash = [](const Key& k){ return k.i; };

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<Key, int, decltype(hash)> m;
    m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(1), std::forward_as_tuple(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::unordered_map::emplace` perfectly forwards all arguments to the constructor of `std::pair`, so it's as if you had called:

```cpp
// value_type is defined as std::pair<...> for a std::unordered_map
value_type(std::forward<Args>(args...)
```

In general, `.emplace` forwards all arguments to the `value_type` of standard library containers.

For `std::unordered_map`, this opens up countless possibilities, because now you can:

- call unary constructors, like `.emplace(std::pair{key, value})`
- call binary constructors, like `.emplace(key, value)`
- call other constructors, like `.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(key_args...), std::forward_as_tuple(value_args...))`

`std::unordered_map::try_emplace` is different because it constructs a key separately from the value. It only constructs the full `std::pair` which is stored in the map if the key doesn't exist yet. Obviously, it cannot simply dump all arguments into a `std::pair` and requires some separation.

---

*Note: for most intents and purposes, `try_emplace` is preferred over `emplace`. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76477970/5740428).*

*Note: everything said here equally applies to `std::map`.*